# AWS with Postfix / Dovecot - Can't access port (25,110)

Tags: postfix, amazon-web-services, email-server, dovecot, amazon-route53

Currently I have installed Postfix and Dovecot to my AWS Instance.
I am able to ping and open dovecot / postfix at port (25,110) at my localhost using:

```
telnet localhost 25

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ip-172-31-16-10.us-west-2.compute.internal ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.4/8.14.4; Sun, 10 Jul 2016 09:05:28 GMT
```

or

```
telnet localhost 110

Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
+OK Dovecot ready.
```

I have Elastic IP, and inside at my privacy group is several:

[image]

For DNS, I am using Route 53.
My zone for domain contain:

```
mail.domain.com.  A  52.89.176.73
domain.com.  MX  10 mail.domain.com
```

At postfix - main.cf I have **"inet_interfaces = all"** , and my grep is several:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10025               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any solution for it?

Comment: Please show your complete `main.cf`; omit sensitive data, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output of `netstat`:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
```

That shows that postfix still only listens to the SMTP port on localhost, otherwise I would expect to see `0.0.0.0:25` as the local address. Did you restart postfix after changing the main.cf?

Is your security group assigned to your instance?

Comment: I try to restart, this is what i am getting:
Shutting down postfix:                                     [FAILED]
Starting postfix:                                          [  OK  ]

Also yes for security group. It's assigned to my instance.